# ConfigService of nest cannot pull .env variable

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

I wanted to implement the [ConfigService](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) of Nestjs v8.1.1

I've place the .env file in the project's root (not src folder) and the file has this content:

```
HOST=http://localhost
PORT=8088
```

The app.Module.ts is enriched with the import:

```
@Module({
  imports: [ 
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      cache: true,
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }), 
   ...]
```

I've tried without the options and with these listed options.

When it is trying to get the value of the variable, it results in

```
var address = this.configService.get('HOST', 'http://localhost')
                                     ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')
```

FYI the code is run in an extended class, which should not make a difference.

```
export default class KsqldbSignalsClient extends ClientProxy {

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {
    super()
  }
    
  async connect(): Promise<any> {
    var address = this.configService.get('HOST', 'http://localhost')
    ...
```

Any hint (even confirmation that it works for you) is appreciated.

Comment: That means the `ConfigService` hasn't been instantiated. Have you decorated the `KsqldbSignalsClient` class with `@Injectable()`?

Comment: @msrumon That was it. Thanks

Comment: @msrumon, please post it as answer, so I can mark it for others.

Answer (score 1):

Decorate the `KsqldbSignalsClient` class with `@Injectable()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**
Install the 2 packages below

https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

**Step 2:**

```
@Module({
  imports: [ 
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      host: process.env.HOST,
      port: process.env.PORT,
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }), 
   ...]
```

**Step 3:**

Then inside you KsqldbSignalsClient class or anywhere
simply get the value like,

```
var address = process.env.HOST;
```

Comment: The idea of config service is to access all env variables via the config service instead of a direct approach.